# $L^{p}$ Contractions in Probability Theory

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the (Banach) space $L^{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ of random variables with finite $p$-th moment, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $p\in[1,\infty]$.

I am interested in studying and constructing (non-trivial) contraction mappings on $L^{p}$, i.e. operators $T:L^{p}\rightarrow L^{p}$ with
$$\| T(X)-T(Y) \|_{p} \;\leq\; M \|X-Y\|_{p} \tag{1}$$
for all $X,Y\in L^{p}$, where $0\leq M<1$.

By non-trivial, I mean examples apart from obvious choices such as $T(X)=\alpha X$ with $\alpha\in[0,1)$.

Standard references for probability theory often establish the *contractive property* of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\;\cdot\;|\;\mathcal{G}\,]$ with $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$. However, in this case $M=1$.

**1. Do you know any (non-trivial) examples of contraction mappings on $L^{p}$ in the field of probability theory.**

Wikipedia defines [contraction operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory)) as bounded linear operators with operator norm smaller or equal to $1$, which then perfectly fits the example of the conditional expectation. [Contraction mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) on the other hand are defined as in (1).

**2. Do operators necessarily need to be linear, in order to satisfy (1)? What is the reason to define contraction operators in this manner?**

Comment: You can take any contraction $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and consider $T$ defined via $T(X)(\omega) = f(X(\omega))$. Then, $T$ is a contraction. In particular, this yields many nonlinear contractions.